# How to make mockup screenshots without VB

Tags: windows-xp, mockups

I am looking for a program to make mockup screenshots with. I first found out I could do it with Visual Basic (uglier names I have yet to hear a programming language being called) from [joelonsoftware.com](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000033.html). I don't want to start learning VB now, especially since I am still in the process of learning Java. I then found [mockupscreens.com](http://www.mockupscreens.com), with the searchstring "how to make mockup screenshots". But seeing as I am going to use this program quite infrequently, I don't think paying $80 for it is worth it.

The mockups I'd like to do would be mainly for Windows XP (perhaps also for GNOME, KDE and Mac OSX, but these are not top-priority).

Edit: Balsamiq is suggested, but this is also a non-free program.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/)

Comment: This is a good answer... It "looks" like pen and Paper, but its cleaner

Comment: I finally bought this. Why? Because the idea behind it (something like "Not pixelperfect, sketchy is easier to change") is great. Making mockups with it is fast, which it should be.

Answer (score 8):

Visio works well, if you have it.

Personally, I like paper and a pen. Then I can't get bogged down in the LOOK of it, and go more for the usability and function. Same with websites.

Once you have the form infront of a customer, you have zero room to move - it you dont deliver it pixel-perfect, they get..... angry. :)

Comment: +1 for paper prototyping. Quick to make, quick to change.

Comment: +1 for pen and paper too.  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001091.html

Comment: Agreed on pen and paper.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to learn the language to use the visual forms designer from Visual Studio to create mockups. Furthermore, the [Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) of Visual Studio is freely available in several languages, namely VB, C# and C++. Take your pick. All ship with the same forms designer that generates backend code in one of the languages. But if you only need the designer, the code might not be relevant for you.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Visio used to come with a template containing common Windows UI elements for this purpose. I don't know if it still does.

Comment: Agree this is probably the best option, however if he doesn't want to pay $80 for the other solution he probably doesn't want to buy visio either.

Answer (score 2):

[Jeff Attwood posted about this on CodingHorror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001091.html) - where he mentions [Powerpoint prototyping](http://blogs.msdn.com/jensenh/archive/2006/01/06/510069.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

pen and paper, or if possible, whiteboard. Once you have something you personally think could work I'd go for as rough a computerized model as you can so you don't spend time agreeing font size before the workflow etc is done. The tool I have used here is my visual designer of Visual Studio (it doesn't look too good with screenshots, only good enough to convey what you'd like to build).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, C# Express would be well for this, as like VB, it has a GUI designer, but it is also syntactically similar to Java, so - given what you are trying to learn and do with this, it might be a nice fit.

Answer (score 1):

[Pencil](http://www.evolus.vn/Pencil/Screenshots.html)  (runs within firefox)

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty exhaustive list here:
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuiPrototypingTools

Important point is whether the tool has "black&white" (or "hand-drawn") skin for your mockups, as already commented by others. Many of the tools (including my own, MockupScreens) do.

Answer (score 0):

wxGlade would work as well, plus it's free software.

Answer (score 0):

http://balsamiq.com/ was already mentioned, but I want to explain why I like it.
It will allow you to sketch up a screenshot, and it still looks like a pen and paper version, or a whiteboard discussion.

If you get to detailed on your screenshot, then the customer thinks you are "done" and does not understand whats taking you so long to finish the project. So this "sketchyness" serves as another layer of abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

[MockupUI](http://mockupui.com/examples/) is another one, but its mockups don't look like hand-drawn. They look like the real thing and with real data. It lets you draw wireframes as well as native widgets inheriting their appearance from your OS configuration (aka Windows visual style).

About high-fidelity mockups: The risk that a customer thinks that it's "already done" is minimal as long as you do your mockups during the design specification phase of your project (that's before starting to code). On the contrary, a sketch may be too abstract for the customer to digest, unless he is a software designer too. Sketches are for developers not customers.

Wireframes (or sketches) and mockups are not the same thing and they have different uses. One is to explain functionality, the other is a representation of what the product will look like. Check out Yisela's post about [the difference between wireframes and mockups](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30860/what-is-the-difference-between-wireframes-and-mockups).

Your question was about mockup screenshot software, but you ended-up buying a pretty powerful wireframing software.